# A design pattern to handle similar groupings of objects with different multiplicities?

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstraction

I am designing a program that allows you to create an object with traits and then add it to a database. For example, a renting property like so:

```
public class Property
{
    PropertyType type;
    int bedrooms;
    int bathrooms;
    double squareFootage;
    boolean furnished;
}
```

Then, you or other users can search the database for objects based on those traits. But here are the restrictions:

- All properties have one of each trait defined (you can't leave one trait blank)
- You may search for properties by any one trait, combination of traits, or no traits (to see all). AND you can specify a multiplicity for each trait. For example, you can specify a HOUSE with 2, 3 or 4 bedrooms and 2 or 3 bathrooms. Thereby not putting restrictions on square footage or furnishing.

This poses a problem, as the existence of a trait in the search criteria may or may not exist, and may have a multiplicity. Here is my current solution to hold the search criteria:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    ArrayList<PropertyType> type;
    ArrayList<int> bedrooms;
    ArrayList<int> bathrooms;
    ArrayList<double> squareFootage;
    ArrayList<boolean> furnished;
}
```

The problem is that when I want to add another trait to `Property`, I have to add it to both these classes (and probably more in database controller etc) and add additional functions for it in each. What is a design pattern I can utilize to make this code more modular and abstract?

Essentially, a good answer would be a solution that allows the addition or removal of traits by only changing one class/file.

Simply using an interface `Trait` with an overidden function `getTrait()` wouldn't work because the return types aren't the same across all traits.

EDIT: I have to implement a `SearchCriteria` class because this program is run on a client/server connection, so `SearchCriteria` will be serialized and sent over a socket, not sent directly to the database.

Comment: If you have everything in a database, just use queries to return the properties as needed. Do waste time writing code that does what the database can do.

Comment: People don't want to search on exact square footage. They search on "more than x square feet" (or perhaps "between x and y square feet"). It depends on the nature of the trait how people want to search on it, it's not a 1:1 mapping. For "furnished", it's going to be "furnished, unfurnished or don't care" - which you can represent with a `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: True but this doesn't solve my problem. Making `squareFootage` a different type of variable/object in each class makes the problem worse. And the `java.lang.Boolean` helps make it a little cleaner but that was already solved by having the `ArrayList<boolean>` being empty. My main problem is having the traits being easily open to additions/removals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a handful of traits, and they're fundamental to your business model, it's totally reasonable to have to change more than one class when you add a new trait or want to change the type of behavior of one of those traits.

However, if you're trying to come up with a model that can handle dynamically adding different types of traits to your object, you may consider not encoding the traits as class properties at all. Rather, have your model contain a list of Traits, where each Trait knows its TraitType. Each TraitType has a specific shape for its data, as well as a specific shape for its Criteria. This would enable you to define your model in a file or database somewhere, and change it on demand, and only have to change the *code* when you identify a new TraitType. But it would also be an enormous amount of work, and would only be worthwhile if your business needs require a high degree of configurability.